Hausdorff formula for Dilatation operator
Using the Hausdorff formula I can find the dilation operator at all position:
$$
e^{i x^\rho P_\rho} D e^{-i x^\rho P_\rho}=D+\left[D,-i x^\rho P_\rho\right]+\frac{1}{2}\left[\left[D,-i x^\rho P_\rho\right],-ix^\sigma P_\sigma\right]+\ldots.\tag{1}
$$
But isn't the second term zero?
By definition $$D=-ix^\mu \partial_\mu, \qquad P_\mu=-i\partial_\mu\tag{2}$$ then:
$$\begin{align}
\left[D,-i x^\rho P_\rho\right] &= [-ix^\mu\partial_\mu, -ix^\rho(-i\partial_\rho)] \\&= -ix^\mu\partial_\mu(-ix^\rho(-i\partial_\rho)) - -ix^\rho(-i\partial_\rho)(-ix^\mu\partial_\mu) \\ &= (-i)^3 x^\mu\partial_\mu(x^\rho(\partial_\rho)) - (-i)^3 x^\rho\partial_\rho(x^\mu\partial_\mu)\\ &= i  x^\mu\partial_\mu(x^\rho\partial_\rho) - i x^\rho\partial_\rho(x^\mu\partial_\mu)\\ &=0
\end{align}\tag{3}
$$
With renaming of indices, this is exactly the same. Very confused because this shouldn't be the case.

Hint: Be careful to distinguish between operators, variables, constants and eigenvalues. In particular, the $x$s in eqs. (1) & (2) are of  different natures.

In the sense that the $x^\rho$ in front of the operator $P_\rho$ is not part of the operator so can be put outside  of the commutator? But "$x$" variables that are part of the operator cannot ?

I used the same logic to calculate the commutation relations of operators of the conformal group, and my result was correct. So, the idea is that what is part of the operator should be calculated within the brackets. Otherwise, can we put any variables or constants outside?

According to your definition, $D=x^{\rho}P_{\rho}$, so, yes, your result is correct. This is because $D\sim \pm ix^{\rho}P_{\rho}$, which is the argument of the exponentials. It's as if I have something of the form $e^{\alpha A}Ae^{-\alpha A}$. This expression equals to $A$ because the exponential of $A$ commutes with $A$

"This shouldn't be the case". Why? This is a standard feature of Campbell's identity.

As @Qmechanic points out, you seem to be interested in the
subalgebra of the conformal group
$$
[D,P_\mu]=iP_\mu,
$$
and wonder what a translation of the dilation operator D would be, the translation parameter being $x^\rho$, so the Campbell identity truncates,
$$
e^{i x^\rho P_\rho} D e^{-i x^\sigma P_\sigma}=D+\left[D,-i x^\rho P_\rho\right]+\frac{1}{2}\left[\left[D,-i x^\rho P_\rho\right],-ix^\sigma P_\sigma\right]+\ldots. \\
=D-  x^\rho P_\rho.\tag{1}
$$
Restricting yourself  to the coordinate representation (2) can only confuse you, but, indeed, the operator outcome vanishes.

Thanks so much. My last question is that they usually start with the operator that leave the origin invariant and they call it a different way, for example $\Delta$ for the dilation operator instead of D. In your formula (1) they would conclude that $D=\Delta -x^\rho P_\rho = \Delta -ix^\rho \partial_\rho$. In the logic of translating the operator, why don't we start with $\Delta$ between the exponential? Does the subalgebra that constitute of operator that leave the origin invariant satisfy the same commutation relation as the whole conformal group ?

“They”? I don’t understand your comment. Do you fully appreciate the difference between a Lie algebra and its realizations/representations?

For example, in Di Francesco's book named Conformal Field Theory. Probably not, because I am missing something.

I have no access to your text, so I can't read it with you. A realization is a set of operators like your (2) (acting on x and its functions, which leaves the origin invariant)  that satisfies the conformal algebra, and here the Lie subalgebra (1)-- whose combinatorics were strictly used in this answer. Restricted to your realization (2), the combinatoric Lie identity (1) of mine  yields zero.
